# Counting entries in sub/subarray

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a chat.
I have an array that contains the info regarding the room
(in the example below, 2 rooms (the lounge, the beach)).

I have an issue when I have an empty room (in the example the beach), as it contains by default no user, (which is a Null user).

```
$roomNusers=Array ( 
  [The Lounge] => 
        Array ( [id] => 1 
                [privacy] => public 
                [users] => Array 
                   [QUICHE POIREAU] => Array
                       [smiley] => smi_smile.gif
                       [name] => QUICHE POIREAU 
                       [state] => NULL
                       [id] => 1 ) 
                   [JOHN DOE] => Array
                       [smiley] => smi_smile.gif 
                       [name] => Joe FRANC 
                       [state] => 
                       [id] => 40 )
   [The Beach] => Array
      [id] => 2 
      [privacy] => public 
      [users] => Array 
           [Null] => Array 
                 [smiley] => Null
                 [name] => Null
                 [state] => Null
                 [id] => Null
```

I am trying to count, in my array, the number of users currently present in the room.
Looking around Stack Overflow, I managed to find the solution I wanted:

```
foreach($roomNusers as $room => $value)
    {
      echo $room.' user count:'.count($room['users'])
    }
```

This output:

```
The lounge user count: 2
The beach user count: 1
```

My issue is that it counts the user [null] in the beach.

How can I count the number of users not null per room?

I thought of a workaround with something similar to:

```
$countperroom= .count($room['users'])-1;
if(isset(end([$room]['users']))){$countuser+1;}
```

In this, the last user is empty, I do not add an user, but I do not know how to write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than counting the number of values in `$room['users']`, you could count the number of keys after filtering them to remove empty keys:

```
foreach ($rooms as $name => $room) {
    $users = count(array_filter(array_keys($room['users'])));
    echo "$name: $users users\n";
}
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
The Lounge: 2 users
The Beach: 0 users
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qjC0j)

Comment: great, thank you very much for you input, and i really appreciated the time you took to create the example! <3